# How to do a sql conditional joining on multiples tables?

Tags: sql, join

I have an already existing SQL request that join 8 tables togethers, I need to add 3 mores tables to add a facultative information to my data.

For this task, we can ignore 6 tables (bundled in `other_tables`) :

[image: db schema]

The part in the red box is the one I got to add. I want to only add `request` that respect a few conditions. If none are found, I still want my person, but with no data in the `Request` column.

So far I tried this, but the multiple `left join` seems ugly and too inclusive.

```
Select [...], request.Id
From [Action] inner join [other tables on ...] inner join
    Person on Action.PersonId = Person.Id left JOIN 
request as r on r.PersonId = Person.Id left JOIN
Subject as s on s.SubjectId = r.SubjectId left JOIN
TypeRequest tr on tr.IDSujet = s.SubjectId
Where 
([already existing conditions]) and typeRequest = 'MOVE' (?)
```

And to rephrase once more what I want : Get me all `actions` according to some filter (on *other tables*), also get the `person` they are linked to. If that `person` has a `Request` of a specific `TypeRequest`, add the `Request id` to the data row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the query above work?
"seems ugly and too inclusive" is a bit vague.
are you getting the results you want?
you can also move part of the where clause to the join like this:

```
    Select [...], request.Id
From [Action] inner join [other tables on ...] inner join
    Person on Action.PersonId = Person.Id left JOIN 
request as r on r.PersonId = Person.Id left JOIN
Subject as s on s.SubjectId = r.SubjectId left JOIN
TypeRequest tr on tr.IDSujet = s.SubjectId **and typeRequest = 'MOVE'**
Where 
([already existing conditions])
```

Comment: I wrote "too inclusive" because the query with the extra `left join` return more result (although it shouldn't change). And the 3 `left join` feels ugly because _I feel_ It should be `left join`  on `request` and `inner join` on `subject` and on `typeRequest`.

Comment: IF you have three tables that have 1 field in common you can only get the results from all three tables with a select and 2 joins. maybe your tables are overly-normalized.

Comment: I used what you suggested in your answer and it seems to work. Thanks. (I can't change the db structure too).